# Error while installing collabnet SVN 5.2.3 on windows 2012 server

Tags: svn, collabnet

Hi we are installing collabnet SVN 5.2.3 on windows 2012 server 64 bit, but getting error

> a file that is required cannot be installed because the cabinet file C:\users..disk1.cab has an invalid signature.This may indicate the cabinet file is corrupt.

[image: Error]

Edit : Additional info Windows server 2012 no longer trusts any SHA1 signed code.

Comment: Have you tried contacting CollabNet's support?

Comment: Yes, they are providing limited support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue referring below link.
[Installation-Error-invalid-digital-signature](https://support.sentryone.com/s/article/Installation-Error-invalid-digital-signature)